# Marginal effect of asset in a strategy

Tags: equities, quant-trading-strategies, backtesting

Im trying to develop a stastical arbitrage strategy that depends on a universe of assets and in a brief way, they replicate some factor(s), index(s), etf(s), etc, and then trade residuals. So, after having some interesting results, I was wondering how the universe selection affects the performance.

My approach until now consists of using an initial cutoff by liquidity (spread, turnover, etc) and model the strategy with this constant (K) of symbols. I think this method has a good economic reason and its relatively simple, but obviously depends on the cutoff.

The question arises when tunning parameters of the strategy, because upon this K symbols, some contribute more to the the performance than others, so its marginal contribution will be different. Naturally,  using the set K - {symbol A} performs different from using K - {symbol B} or K - {symbol A,symbol C}. And perhaps including symbol A damage the strategy in most situations.

Some thoughts about this:

- Ranking by performance will sure lead to overfitting and also is
  computationally expensive (Trying all sets of sizes between [K -
  min(#symbols), and K])
- Since I use this K symbols to replicate some factor, index, etf, etc,...Maybe compute marginal effect of the inclusion of a symbol, by using the variance explained of a 1D PCA (Market Portfolio), and use it to select this K symbols, without looking performance. I say 1D for simplicity but it could be more dimensions.
- Just use the liquidity approach that I mentioned before. Keep it simple and parsimonious.
  I like this and its tempting, but also think that this is suboptimal and maybe there are better ways, idk. Sure inside this K symbols, some just are not fitted for the strategy or depend on external factors that the other symbols dont, so they have a life on their own.

Consider that I have a SOOS data that I havent touched and have been careful with survivorship bias.

I will appreaciate is you give me some guidance on how to handle this. Thanks